# Debugging a gem in ruby-mine using the integrated debugger instead of pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rubymine, pry

I can't debug the test cases (with the ruby-mine's debugger) of a project which is being used as an external library in one of my different projects. I **can** debug it using pry but not with the integrated ruby-mine debugger. 
It doesn't have any configurations added and I am not sure what to add for this project. It doesn't run on it's own on a rails server, it is just being used as an external library.
If Pry can help so I am pretty sure I can debug it with ruby-mine's integrated debugger also. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in necessary test files and create a Run configuration for running them?

Comment: Yes. With Pry everything works fine. I was not able to create run configurations because that is a gem which doesn't run on rails-server, it is being consumed in another project.

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly you're trying to debug?